# Export cucumber test from Jira with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have configured a webhook in Jira. Always when someone create/update a Xray-test-issue, the webhook get activated. Jira sends the key from the Issue to the  Jenkins URL.
The Jenkins job is parameterized(ISSUE). Then I'm using the *Xray for JIRA Jenkins Plugin* 
[image: XRAY addon]

I try to use the ISSUE in the field. This doesn't work. It uses "${ISSUE}" and not the value. In a bash script I can use the variable.

How does this works?

Comment: Try removing the curly braces.

Comment: hey, doesn't work with $ISSUE